# How to set and get the default value in date_select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

So i have a edit form which has year start and end date. I want to show db stored values as default dates.

I have tried this

```
 <%= f.input :year_start_date, :label => 'Year Start Date', :as => :date_select, :include_blank => false,
                      :input_html => { :id => 'y_start_date'}, prompt: { day: year_start_date.day, month: Date::MONTHNAMES[year_start_date.month], year: year_start_date.year}, data: year_start_date %>
```

So its fine and started to show db stored values.

But the issue is when am changing only month, parameters will be

```
"year_start_date(1i)" => "",  "year_start_date(2i)" => "3",  "year_start_date(3i)" => ""
```

and in the controller am doing 
`[ school_params['year_start_date(1i)'], school_params['year_start_date(2i)'], school_params['year_start_date(3i)'] ].join('-').to_date`

since it contains empty strings it throws invalid date error.

I want the default values( in this case date and year) when nothing is selected. How to achieve this?

Edit 1:

params

```
{
                "utf8" => "✓",
             "_method" => "patch",
  "authenticity_token" => "abcffdgfdgfgfgf==",
              "school" => {
                         "name" => "Test School",
                     "board_id" => "1",
    "board_registration_number" => "",
                    "subdomain" => "testschool",
                        "email" => "",
                      "website" => "",
                      "address" => "NA",
                         "city" => "NA",
                      "pincode" => "",
                   "country_id" => "1",
                "country_state" => "Tamil Nadu",
                        "phone" => "NA",
                     "inc_year" => "",
                   "handler_id" => "14451",
          "year_start_date(1i)" => "",
          "year_start_date(2i)" => "1",
          "year_start_date(3i)" => "",
            "year_end_date(1i)" => "",
            "year_end_date(2i)" => "",
            "year_end_date(3i)" => ""
  },
              "button" => "",
          "controller" => "sat/schools",
              "action" => "update",
                  "id" => "2"
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a suggestion: use `datepicker` js plugin.

Comment: convert into date format

Comment: @uzaif am coverting to date_format by using .to_date. Even i tried using Date.new( school_params['year_start_date(1i)'].to_i, school_params['year_start_date(2i)'].to_i, school_params['year_start_date(3i)'].to_i ) and still getting the same error.

Comment: did you check in controller by using raise params.inspect when form submit what date format did you got?

Comment: Can you inspect your form object & share that inspect here ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that ugly date/datetime input you can simply use the date picker provided by the browser without having to add additional libraries:

`f.input :year_start_date, :label => 'Year Start Date', as: :string, input_html: { type: "date" }`